# Households' wealth deciles by country

Tags: economics

I'm looking for data (either directly the deciles, or data allowing me to compute the deciles) on households' wealth by country on the recent years.

Much of the data that I have found only include the top 1%, 5%, 10%, 50% and the bottom 50%, or something of the sort. Also, I've never been able to find the underlying data in order to compute the deciles myself.

The only country for which I've found the data seems to be France, with their INSEE's ["Patrimoine net des ménages"](https://www.insee.fr/fr/statistiques/5371259?sommaire=5371304). The data is downloadable, and in the couple sheets there is, one lists the deciles.

Is there any place to find this type of data, and this data in particular? Thanks a lot!